# ekf odom and compass robot_localization

Tags: navigation, ekf, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I have a compass sensor and a odom sensor, this start in the position 0,0,0. The compass it's in the correct position but when i echo the odometry filtered It is delaying it will respect the GPS signal.

Any answer?

EDIT 1:
This is a rosbag with the sensor topics https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kwbd1yaxixpf8m/rosbag.bag?dl=0
This is a tree graph, nodes graph and rviz capture.
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

Red color /odometry/filtered and green color position/GPS
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

The position GPS is in absolute coordinates.
The ekf launch is this, with the base link compass transformation:

```
<!-- EKF -->
<launch>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 base_link compass 20" />

<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization" clear_params="true">
  <param name="frequency" value="30"/>  
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>  
  <param name="two_d_mode" value="true"/>

  <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>

  <param name="odom0" value="position/gps"/>
  <param name="imu0" value="compass/data"/> 


  <rosparam param="odom0_config">[true,  true,  false, 
                                  false, false, false, 
                                  false, false, false, 
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false, 
                                 false, false, true, 
                                 false, false, false, 
                                 false, false, false,
                                 false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
  <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>

  <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>

  <param name="print_diagnostics" value="false"/>

  <!-- ======== ADVANCED PARAMETERS ======== -->

  <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="2"/>
  <param name="imu0_queue_size" value="10"/>

  <param name="debug"           value="false"/>
  <param name="debug_out_file"  value="/home/tmoore/Desktop/debug_ekf_localization.txt"/>

  <rosparam param="process_noise_covariance">[0.05, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.02, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.015]</rosparam>

       <rosparam param="initial_estimate_covariance">[1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]</rosparam>

</node>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213717/ekf-odom-and-compass-robot_localization/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-07-14**:
Sorry, to clarify: you have wheel encoder odometry, a magnetometer, and a GPS? Are you using `navsat_transform_node`? Perhaps you can give me some more information about your setup.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-07-15**:
@Porti77 Better post the solution you found as an answer and mark it as an answer so that others can tell the question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!!
I already solved my problem , the error was that i wasnt including the time stamp in the topics of sensors and these become crazy the filter, now the system is working well!! Regards

---

Originally posted by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) with karma: 183 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1